# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sinch voice call

Tags: java, android, android-studio, voip, sinch

I'm making an app where i want to add voice call function using **SINCH** . First 2 days it works fine  but now it is not working , when i run the code android studio show the following error :
**javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x74a32b4c88: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer**

I'm using this code  https://github.com/agusibrahim/SinchVoiceCall-Example

Please help me to solve it